# how to set the username and password in the asp.net web.config file of funnelweblog?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, funnelweb

im trying to get the funnelweb blog application to run on my machine, ive set up the username and password in the web.config file but when i try to login, i get the message "Invalid username or password. Please try again."

```
 <authentication mode="Forms" >
    <forms loginUrl="~/admin/login"   timeout="40320" cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="~/" name="FunnelWeb" slidingExpiration="true">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
            <user  name="admin" password="admin"/>
        </credentials>
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Have you used the correct username and password?

Comment: yes, ive used the admin,admin user,pass combo to login, but it doesnt authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the version that I have **2.1.0.644** you have update the **My.config** file. If you have updated a different config file you will need to remove that to avoid any conflicts. Then update the My.config file keys for username and password with what you would like.

ALSO of note depending on if you are using the compiled or the source code versions of hte downloads the My.config file name may need to be updated.

1. Compiled file name: My.config.sample - you will need to drop the ".sample"
2. Source Code file name: My.config - no change to the file name needed.

I have looked at the [FunnelWebHQ](http://www.funnelweblog.com/getting-started) website and their walk through has no mention of this as the instructions do not seem to be inline with the new version of the application. Yes it is confusing and there have been multiple requests to update the install documentation.
Hope this helps.